# FlatList with Firestore? React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm sure this is something that is pretty common but can't seem to get it figured out. Each user has a "books" array in Firestore, and this is what I want to be returned in the Flatlist, where am I going wrong? The first day with firebase so I'm pretty sure its something basic. Thanks :)

```
                <FlatList
                    data={() => { db.collection('users').doc(userEmail).data() }}
                    numColumns={2}
                    ListEmptyComponent={
                        <View style={styles.flatListEmpty}>
                            <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Add Books Below</Text>
                        </View>
                    }
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <View style={styles.flatListStyle}>
                            <Text>book</Text>
                        </View>
                    )}
                />
```

then this is the database:

[image]

Comment: How did you pass email as record key?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that query to firebase is asynchronous action, so you need to resolve that action then store the result to the state of component and assign that state to flatlist. Example:

```
const Component = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState();

    const getData = async () => {
        const snapshot = await db.collection('users').doc(userEmail).get()

        setData(snapshot.data())
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <FlatList
        data={data.books}
        numColumns={2}
        ListEmptyComponent={
            <View style={styles.flatListEmpty}>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Add Books Below</Text>
            </View>
        }
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.flatListStyle}>
                <Text>book</Text>
            </View>
        )}
    />
    )
}
```

Comment: getting some errors with this one but appreciate the logic behind it. Confused about what the useEffect is doing? It was throwing errors so I removed it. after removing it I'm getting the error 'undefined is not an object". Another question, Is there a way to go all the way to the book level instead of stopping at email level? Right now you are stopping after the .doc(userEmail). Thank you!

Comment: if you drop the .doc(userEmail), firebase will return all records of user. In this case, I suggest to make a new collection that is books and link with users by id. And the useEffect is React hook for functional component. If you are using class component, use componentDidMount instead.

Comment: right ok thanks for the clarification. I want the list to update when a new book is added, right now in order to show newly added books, I need to reload the app. Would I just use onSnapshot or something?

Comment: Yeah, just go with onSnapshot