# Displaying data from Firestore into React Native FlatList did not work

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm using the React Native `FlatList` module to show data that is stored in an `firestore` collection. This data should rendered into an content box with an colored background.
Actually, when I render the corresponding `Screen`, I get as many content boxes as objects are stored into database, but no single field is rendered into the view. I also can print the data object to the console, so querying data should work.

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(query(collection(db, 'Announcement')), (querySnap) => {
            const announcements = []
            querySnap.forEach((announcement) => {
                announcements.push({ ...announcement.data() })
                console.log(announcement.data())
                setContent(announcements)
                setLoading(false)
            })
        })
        unsubscribe()
    },[])


    const renderAnnouncement = ({ item }) => {
        return(
            <View style={ styles.boxItem }>
                <Text style={ styles.date }>{ item.date }</Text>
                <Text style={ styles.title }>{ item.title }</Text>
                <Text style={ styles.body }>{ item.body }</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }


    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={ styles.container }>
            <FlatList
                data={ content }
                renderItem={ renderAnnouncement }
                keyExtractor={ item => item.id }
                ListEmptyComponent={ handleEmptyList }
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

I have structured my data in firestore on the following way:

```
Announcements
    - Document-ID
        - message
            - title: string
            - body: string
            - date: string
            - id: number

    - Document-ID
        - message
            - title: string
            - body: string
            - date: string
            - id: number

... and so on
```

I read related topics here, but all the hints given there, did not solve my issue. Did someone of you have an hint?

Comment: Could you please share your Firebase structure?

Comment: I added the structure in my initial post.

Comment: Have you already checked this [tutorial](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage-with-flatlists) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63370763/13171940)?

Comment: I fixed the issue after removing the "message" node in my data structure. With this the code above works.

Comment: Good job on finding the solution to your own question. @taathy could you post your answer as a formal answer to help other users that have a similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72001282/displaying-data-from-firestore-into-react-native-flatlist-did-not-work#comment127665779_72001282) by [@taathy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17243293/taathy):

> I fixed the issue after removing the "message" node in my data structure. With this the code above works.